# How to build wxShapeFramework with CodeBlock

Tags: codeblocks, wxwidgets

If you used to use wxShapeFramework, please help me to build it on Windows 10 with CodeBlock, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal, change to the `build` directory of your wxSF installation and type `create_build_files.bat`. Press `Enter` then select `1)` for a Code::Blocks project.

This should create the workspace file in the build directory and project files for each of the samples in their respective directories.